# Bootstrap Search Box uses the wrong url

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

This my first post in stackoverflow and I am pretty new to Bootstrap and Django and probably it is a silly thing but I could not find the solution. SearchBox on Bootstrap navbar does not go to the correct url.

I am trying to add a search engine by using ListView on my test project. If I use the simple html search form, it works, it uses correct url (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/crmapp/search/?q=SearchedText`) and brings the results from database. However, if I use the searchbox which is on my NavBar (Bootstrap4), it does not go to the correct url and does not bring anything. On my browser I see that it is going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=SearchedText`.

Other links on my navbar are working fine. I don't know if it is related but If I extend the ListView templates to base.html, they don't show even simple html. When I remove `{% extends 'base.html' %}`, the page displays the content fine.

```py
**base.html**
    <!--Navbar Starts Here-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light mb-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'crmapp' %}">CrmApp <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}


          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {{user.username}}
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change password</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Profile</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'mytasks' %}">My Tasks</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logoutuser' %}">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">    
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name='q' type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value='Search'>Search</button>
        </form>
        {% else %}

          <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'loginuser' %}">Login</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary ml-2 mr-2" href="{% url 'registeruser' %}">Register</a>  

          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method='GET' action="{% url 'search_results' %}">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name='q' value={{request.GET.q}} placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Navbar Ends-->
```

**The simple search form that works fine:**

```html
<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
  <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value='Search'>Search</button>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```py
path('search/', TaskSearch.as_view() , name='search_results'),
```

**views.py**

```py
class TaskSearch(ListView):
    model = Tasks
    template_name = 'search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query= self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Tasks.objects.filter ( Q(subject__icontains=query) | Q(status__icontains=query) )
        return object_list
```

Can you please help me to fix SearchBox in Navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<form>`in the `{% if ... %}`case has no specified `action="..."` in your template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    ...
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">    
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name='q' type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value='Search'>Search</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```